# Conditional density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Let there be a composite system $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{B}$, where $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{B}$ are Hilbert spaces of two subsystems of $A$ and $B$.

Suppose the density matrix of this composite system be $\rho_{AB}$ and suppose that it is not separable.

We can find the density matrix of the system $A$ by tracing out the system $B$:
$$\rho_{A} = \operatorname{tr}_{B}(\rho_{AB}). $$
For simplicity, let the system $B$ be a two-level system. Then $\rho_{A}$ can be written as
$$\rho_{A} = \langle 0|\rho_{AB}|0\rangle +\langle 1|\rho_{AB}|1\rangle. $$

I have the following questions:

1. Can we say that $\langle 0|\rho_{AB}|0\rangle$ is the density matrix of the system $A$ conditioned on having measured the state of the system $B$ to be in $|0\rangle$, and $\langle 1|\rho_{AB}|1\rangle$ is the density matrix of the system $A$ conditioned on having measured the state of the system $B$ to be in $|1\rangle$?
2. The density matrix of the system $A$ depends on the measured state of the system $B$, only if the two systems are entangled. Is this true? Otherwise, if they are separable, the density matrix of the system $A$ is independent of the system $B$?
3. Assuming that statement on the question one is correct, do we need to normalize the density matrices $\langle 0|\rho_{AB}|0\rangle$ and $\langle 1|\rho_{AB}|1\rangle$?

Comment: You should focus on one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2 look correct. And yes, because $Tr(\rho_A) = 1$, then if taking only a part of $\rho_A$, you'll need to normalize it.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Also, does it hold for any state $|b\rangle$ of the system $B$? For example, is $\langle b|\rho_{AB}|b\rangle$ the density matrix of the system $A$ conditioned on having measured the state of the system $B$ to be in a general state $|b\rangle$?

Comment: Yes that is true, as long as, $\rho_A - \langle b |\rho_{AB}|b\rangle$ is orthogonal to $\langle b |\rho_{AB}|b\rangle$.